# Python 3.6 fails to build in QEMU with "failed to get random numbers to initialize Python"

Tags: linux, python-3.x, random, build, qemu

I'm trying to build Python using qemu on Linux. Python 2.7 worked great, no problems, standard build process. Python 3.6, same build process is throwing an error like this:

```
./Programs/_freeze_importlib \
    ./Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py Python/importlib.h
Fatal Python error: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python
```

So I'm thinking this is due to qemu not having /dev/random or /dev/urandom? So either I figure out how to add random to the qemu, or convince Python 3.6 to not require it?

Edit: I'm trying to use PYTHONHASHSEED to get around this, but from what I can tell it has no effect - I can set crazy values like PYTHONHASHSEED=Jeff (which should generate a different error), but no difference. So now I'm thinking its the qemu and environment variables that I am not understanding.

Comment: Here's the line in question: https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Python/random.c#l583

Comment: Thanks for that! I should have mentioned I tried to use PYTHONHASHSEED to get around this - but I'm thinking I must not have used it correctly. I'm going to experiment with that.

Answer (score 6):

Ok - the real answer is to fix the QEMU - which turned out to be easy:

```
mknod -m 444 /dev/random c 1 8
mknod -m 444 /dev/urandom c 1 9
```

Python3.6 is building now - thanks for watching!